# preg_replace_callback: passing in replacement callback as a variable not working

Tags: php, callback, preg-replace-callback

This does not work

```
        $check["pattern"] = "/correct/";
    $callback = "function ($m) { return ucfirst($m[0]);}";
    echo preg_replace_callback($check["pattern"],$callback,"correct" );

output: correct
```

This works

```
        $check["pattern"] = "/correct/";
    echo preg_replace_callback($check["pattern"],function ($m) { return ucfirst($m[0]);},"correct" );

output: Correct
```

Why, and how to make it work with the function stored inside a var? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? I see no reason to store the function inside a variable, to be honest. Nevertheless, if you really want to do this, take a look at [create_function](http://nl.php.net/create_function):

```
<?php
$check["pattern"] = "/correct/";
$callback = create_function('$m', 'return ucfirst($m[0]);');
echo preg_replace_callback( $check['pattern'], $callback, "correct" );

// Output: "Correct"
```

Comment: I am letting my developer users submit preg_replace_callback functions in a hosted solution in a text field :) Yes I know it is not the most secure, but they go through an approval phase. I think this is faster than letting them submit code in github, and I hate mile long php files with hundreds of lines. Database to the rescue...

Comment: It, indeed, it insecure, but as long as you have control over what happens, I guess using create_function would work.

Comment: @giorgio79 Just tested the code. It correctly outputs "Correct".

Comment: Yep, thanks. Stackoverflow makes me wait 10 mintues to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a var_dump on `$callback = "function ($m) { return ucfirst($m[0]);}";` the result is a **string**. In the working situation you pass a Closure (anonymous function) as callback.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) is clear: a Closure is allowed, if you pass a string, it must be the **name** of a function.

Comment: Thanks, this is a correct answer as well. Berry also gave me a working copy and paste solution, so will accept that.